# Mapping objects in angularJS ui.select using "track by"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to use angular-ui's **`ui.select`** to populate a `multiple dropdown field`. I'd like to pass the selected objects to the ng-model and have it mapped to my options, containing objects of the same structure, but not from the same source:

```
<div ng-repeat="training in trainings">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <ui-select multiple ng-model="training.skills" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Wähle Skills...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices group-by="skillTypeGrp" repeat="skill.id as skill in skills | filter: $select.search">
                <span>{{skill.name}}</span>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `trainings` list from `ng-repeat` with an example training looks like this:

```
[{"description": "",
  "skills": [{"type": "tech",
              "name": "C",
              "id": 194}],
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test"}]
```

My `skills` list from `ui-select-choices` contains the same data structure as in `training.skills`:

```
[{"type": "tech",
  "name": "C#",
  "id": 194},
 {"type": "tech",
  "name": "Java",
  "id": 197},
 ...]
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work. The ui-select empties my `training.skills`, showing me an blank select field. I understand that angularjs is not able to map those objects, if they do not origin the same array, like stated in [this blogpost](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/). It suggests using **`track by`** to tell `ui.select` which property to use to map the two lists of objects, but if i change the `ui-select-choices` line to:

```
<ui-select-choices group-by="skillTypeGrp" repeat="skill.id as skill in skills track by skill.id | filter: $select.search">
```

nothing changes.
Is there any possibility to get this running without replacing my objects by their ids like the [single property binding example](http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview) suggests?

Answer (score 4):

You need to reverse `filter` and `track by` to make it work:

```
 <ui-select-choices group-by="skillTypeGrp" repeat="skill in skills | filter: $select.search track by skill.id">
```

It looks strange, but did the trick for me..

Answer (score 2):

If you refer the documentation given at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat 
the `track by` must always be the last expression.

So, as suggested by madc if you change to:

```
 <ui-select-choices group-by="skillTypeGrp" repeat="skill in skills | filter: $select.search track by skill.id">
```

It would work.

Below is the documentation snippet that says about track by being the last expression:

[image: documentation snippet that says about track by being the last expression]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are trying to compare the whole object with its id.

Did you try to use:

```
<ui-select-choices group-by="skillTypeGrp" repeat="skill in skills | filter: $select.search">
    <span>{{skill.name}}</span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Notice I removed "skill.id" from repeat. I think in this way you should compare the objects and hopefully it will work.

Otherwise I would leave the ui-select-choices as you have it and in the ui-select pass an array of IDs (the selected trainings) to match the list. Of course this would imply more coding from your side to update the skills array every time a change occurs.

Hope it helps.